# Format a fraction in java

Tags: java, output

Is there any way to print a fraction in any form? I'm working on a math program and a fraction is much easier to read than 1/2.

If there is any API that can do written math, I would also be glad.

Example:

[image: 1/2 as formatted fraction]

Instead of 1/2

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Are you trying to print 0.5 instead of 1/2?

Comment: It’s *fraction*

Comment: Fraction can be used for display porpose. For internal calculation it is not needed. For display, check out `Latex` =>https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/amsmath/

Comment: You say a fraction, but `1/2` is a faction.  Do you just want it to be split on three different lines?

Comment: Check out [`Fraction`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/Fraction.html)
of Apache's commons-math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a one-liner answer for your question, so try approaching it from a different angle. You could write a method that takes the numerator and denominator as arguments and then return an output string in any format you want, such as `String.format("%d\n---\n%d",numerator,denominator);`

Answer (score 0):

if your printing it without quotes your pretty much just turning it into a decimal because your dividing the 2. An example to avoid this:

`System.out.println("1/2");`

Comment: This does exactly what the OP wants to NOT do. OP wants the numbers to be one on top and one on bottom, not on the same line.